# How to run a file in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a project that I imported into pycharm.  It looks like this:

[image: a screenshot of my python project in pycharm]

The file `grabber.py` references class Fetcher within `fetcher.py` like this:

```
from grabber.fetcher import Fetcher
```

from the root folder `Automaton` I can run `grabber.py` from the command line with this command:

```
python -m grabber.grabber
```

But, I want to run `grabber.py` from pycharm.  When I try I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Automaton/grabber/grabber.py", line 1, in <module>
    from grabber.fetcher import Fetcher
  File "C:\Automaton\grabber\grabber.py", line 1, in <module>
    from grabber.fetcher import Fetcher
ImportError: No module named 'grabber.fetcher'; 'grabber' is not a package
```

How do I get pycharm to run the file the same way I can from the command line?

Comment: It looks like PyCharm isn't finding your packages. I think you need to set working directory for the `PyCharm` run command and check the "Add Source Root to PYTHONPATH" and "Add Contents Root to PYTHONPATH"

Comment: @MattiLyra I checked those setting in `Run->Edit Configurations` and they seem to be in order.  Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was pretty silly.  I was having the problem because I had a package `grabber` and a file within it called `grabber.py`  That name collision caused the problem.  I renamed `grabber.py` and it works.